# A trace inequality with a projector matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, projection-matrices

Suppose $A$ is a matrix with positive eigenvalues ($A$ is not Hermitian), and $P$ is a projector matrix. Is the inequality $\operatorname{Tr}  (PA)\leq \operatorname{Tr}(A)$ correct?

When $A$ and $P$ commute, it is straightforward because  $\operatorname{Tr} (PA)$ is equal to the summation of some of eigenvalues of $A$, and since all eigenvalues of $A$ are positive the inequality holds. But what happens when $A$ and $P$ do not commute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $A$ and $P$ do not commute, the inequality can fail. Counterexample:

$$P = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{ and }\quad A = \begin{bmatrix}5 & -3\\3 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$
It is clear $P$ is a projection operator. It is easy to check $2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $2$. However
$${\rm Tr}(PA) = 5 > 4 = {\rm Tr}(A)$$

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it does hold when $A$ is positive definite?  i.e. $A$ has positive and distinct eigenvalues.

Comment: @Mah The inequality can fail even when $A$ has positive and distinct eigenvalues. In the above example, you can perturb $A$ a little bit (e.g $A \to A' = A + \frac12 P$ ) to remove the degeneracy of the eigenvalues while keeping them positive (eigenvalues becomes $1/2, 7/2$) and at the same time $11/2 = {\rm Tr}(PA') \ge {\rm Tr}(A') = 9/2$.

Comment: oops, eigenvalues of $A'$ should be $1$ and $7/2$.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for helping. So the inequality is true iff $P$ and $A$ commute?

Comment: The inequality is true if $P$ and $A$ commute, it is indeterminate when $P$ and $A$ don't commute.